# Writing a to nested serializer in Django Rest Framework and hitting validator issues

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Whats the best way to write to a nested serializer where the ForeignKey related item already exists?

Example - I have a one-to-many Survey Model and SurveyReponse Models. POST of a new SurveyResponse model where the Survey model hasn't been created yet works without issue, and also the POST of a model where the specific Survey model isn't defined and I default to a specific Survey model. However, trying to provide the field seems to cause validator issues similar to this question asked in the past: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2996
Doesn't seem like just adding validators=[] fixes my issues though.

What I done so far:
I set up my SurveyReponse.create() method to be able to do is to post a SurveyResponse providing NO Survey, and for it to save to a default Survey. 
This works great. 
i.e., a POST of

```
{ "rating": 10 }
```

creates a new SurveyReponse object and also Relates it to the Survey with name: "Default Survey Name"

What else I want to do:
I want to be able to POST providing a specific Survey to relate my SurveyReponse too.

```
{
 "rating": 10,
 "survey": {"name": "Other Survey Name"}
}
```

This works fine with my current code if the Survey doesn't exist yet, however, if the Survey already exists, I hit the unique identifier duplication error

```
{
  "survey": {
    "name": [
      "survey with this name already exists."
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I get around this?
by removing this line,

```
     survey = SurveySerializer(required=False)
```

I'm able to do what I want, but I have to just provide the url to the resource, when I want to be able to just provide the name. (Unless this entire idea is an anti-pattern or something, and in which case, I should always just be writing to the /survey/ object instead)

Sample Survey and Survey Response:

High Level Models:

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        related_name='survey',
        to_field='id',
        null=True,
    )

class SurveyResponse(models.Model):
    """Response to the Survey"""
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        related_name='survey_response',
        to_field='id',
        null=True,
    )
```

Serializers

```
class SurveySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    creator = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='creator.username')
    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        fields = '__all__'

class SurveyResponseSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    '''Question Serializer'''
    creator = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='creator.username')
    survey = SurveySerializer(required=False)
    def create(self, validated_data):
        default_survey_name = "Default Survey Name"
        survey_data = validated_data.pop('survey', None)
        if survey_data is None:
            try:
                survey = Survey.objects.get(name=default_survey_name)
                validated_data['survey'] = survey
            except:
                print("Unable to get Survey, creating a new one")
                survey = Survey.objects.create(
                    name=default_survey_name,
                    description=default_survey_name,
                    creator=self.context['request'].user
                )
                validated_data['survey'] = survey
        else:
            survey, survey_created = Survey.objects.get_or_create(**survey_data)

        validated_data['survey'] = survey
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this series of changes to the Serializer to remove validators and do the the name validation manually during create and update. Let me know if there is a more idiomatic approach!

```
class SurveySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
     creator = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='creator.username')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        if Survey.objects.filter(name=self.validated_data['name']).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("A survey with this name already exists")
        return Survey.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        all_other_survey = Survey.objects.exclude(name=instance.name)
        if all_other_survey.filter(name=self.validated_data['name']).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("A survey with this name already exists (Not counting this instance)")
        else:
            instance.name = self.validated_data['name'] or instance.name
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'name': {
                'validators': [],
            }
        }
```

Comment: What happens when there is an error ? Do you still end up creating or reusing the survey ? Raise should stop all further execution but the extra_kwargs having no validators is what is making me unsure